# Reverting a broken merge and reapplying selected commits with Git

Tags: git, merge, tortoisegit

We recently encountered a problem where a merge somehow led to all the changes leading to one parent being undone in the merge commit, and several commits have been applied after that point. All this has been pushed to our shared origin repository. I want to be able to revert the bad merge and reapply the other change sets. What is the easiest way to do this?

ASCII art example:

```
    A-B-C-D
   /       \
P-Q         M-X-Y-Z
   \       /
    1-2-3-4

  ---time--->
```

The commit M has included changes A to D but all changes 1 to 4 were reverted by that commit.

I would like to be able to revert back, eg. to changeset 4, and reapply changes A-D and X to Z, ideally without manually redoing each change.

If this is not possible, I'd like to hear of the best workarounds - eg. maybe branch from 4, merge in D again being careful not to break anything, then manually reapplying X to Z?

(An ideal situation would be to know how to do this using TortoiseGit, although just knowing the command line should allow me to deduce the rest.)

Comment: Do you want to wind up with `P-Q-1-2-3-4-A-B-C-D-X-Y-Z`?

Comment: I don't care about the order, since almost all of these changes don't conflict in any way, but I would (ideally) like all those changesets there in the end, or equivalent.

Comment: Have you already pushed this upstream, or is it only on your local repo right now?

Comment: Yes, all these changes are upstream on our central repo.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to wind up with something whose logical effect is:

```
P-Q-1-2-3-4-A-B-C-D-X-Y-Z
```

There are a couple of approaches. Let's assume master points to `Z` right now.

---

### Revert the merge commit (safest but messier)

We need to revert the broken merge commit `M` first. We'll do that with:

```
git revert -m 1 M
```

Next, let's re-apply the negated or potentially negated commits:

```
git cherry-pick 1
git cherry-pick 2
git cherry-pick 3
git cherry-pick 4
git cherry-pick A
git cherry-pick B
git cherry-pick C
git cherry-pick D
```

Now we have this:

```
# M reverts some of A..D and 1..4
# !M undoes the logical effect of the merge

    A-B-C-D
   /       \
P-Q         M-X-Y-Z-!M-1'-2'-3'-4'-A'-B'-C'-D'
   \       /
    1-2-3-4
```

This is the safest approach because it doesn't touch any previous history, so no one's upstream repos will be affected. But it's also the messiest because it leaves a lot of detritus. Alas, that's the price you pay for a sloppy merge.

---

### Throw away the broken history (most dangerous but cleanest)

This will require getting consensus from everyone that your approach is sound. You will break people's history, and anyone who has the tainted merge commit `M` will experience issues if you do it this way. But your history will look cleaner.

Because you will break the history of any team members who have the tainted commit until they pull down the remote repository and until they reset their local masters to that point, this is the most dangerous approach.

First, we rewind master back to `Q`, the last commit without problems.

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard Q       # rewind `master` branch to `Q`
```

Next, we need to interactively rebase the broken commit sequence.

```
git checkout Z         # move to Z
git branch tmp         # make a branch pointing to Z
git rebase -i master   # rework this branch onto master
```

You'll be presented with a list of commits in your editor that looks like this:

```
pick aaaaaaa Commit message one
pick bbbbbbb Commit message two
pick ccccccc Commit message three
# ...
```

One of these will be the broken merge commit. Delete this line; save and close.

Git will now apply the commits in the order you asked for, and you will be on tmp. If everything looks good, then reset master:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard tmp
```

Now force-push to origin:

```
git push -f origin master
```

The broken history will be removed and master will point to a new history.

---

### Finally

You should consider asking your team to use something like [nvie's git-flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) to avoid future messiness and prevent snafus.

Update: It looks like nvie abandoned support for git-flow. However, [Peter van der Does forked](https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow) and is maintaining a version

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer John. Just a couple of follow up questions before I decide what to do - 1) Why is it not possible to simply update to 4 and attempt to merge D again, then switch the head to this new merge? 2) How do you see git-flow helping here? We can't actually use it because we need to use GUI tools for source control, but I don't see how it would help in cases such as this because all the changes refer to the master branch and the chance of getting a manual merge wrong when one is needed doesn't seem likely to change.

Comment: 1.) You can do that, but I gathered from your example that `1..4` is at least a few commits. If any of them conflict, you'll be forced to resolve them all simultaneously in a new merge commit, which could be cumbersome. If not, though, then I agree that merging is better. But otherwise, rebasing is much cleaner. Note that either way, you'll still need to get X..Z on there somehow. 2.) I didn't know you were constrained to use GUI tools. If that's true, then yes, `git-flow` won't help much.

Comment: Oh, also, note that updating to `4` will obviously take you down the "dangerous" path, since now you're creating a new version of the historical commits.

Comment: I don't understand what is dangerous about it - wouldn't it just be a new part of the graph which happens to have some of the same code changes as the part we'd no longer use? I'm not particularly interested in how clean the history looks, more in not having to re-do changes 1-4 (which are more like 13 changes, involving many files, some binary). The rebase approach is probably too risky for our team given that I am having to ask here on how to proceed.

Comment: It's dangerous, because you can't get `Z` onto a new `master` without changing history. `Z` depends on `M`, which you don't want to include. If you don't want to include a past, existing commit in your new `master`, then you are creating new history. Anyone who has the current `origin/master` will be pointing to `Z`, but you want them to point to `Z'`, which is history that doesn't exist for them.

Comment: Ok, how about if I drop the requirement to preserve X/Y/Z (and put them back in manually)? I basically need to make a new, working M, redo the work that was in X/Y/Z, and then point the head of origin/master to point to that. Is that possible? If the other members then do a pull, will they be successfully updated to that point?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7339/discussion-between-john-feminella-and-kylotan)